# how to train,test and validate the feed forward neural network for 3 input nodes and 2 output nodes

Tags: random-access

i m having a data set as shown below, how to train,test and validate the feed forward neural network for same data.

```
input data
  [ 0         0         0;
         0   22.9183         0;
         0   45.8366         0;
         0   68.7549         0;
   22.9183         0         0;
   22.9183   22.9183         0;
   22.9183   45.8366         0;
   22.9183   68.7549         0;
   45.8366         0         0;
   45.8366   22.9183         0;
   45.8366   45.8366         0;
   45.8366   68.7549         0;
   68.7549         0         0;
   68.7549   22.9183         0;
   68.7549   45.8366         0;
   68.7549   68.7549         0;
   91.6732         0         0;
   91.6732   22.9183         0;
   91.6732   45.8366         0;
   91.6732   68.7549         0]

output data
 [405.0000         0;
  390.8699   69.7059;
  350.7105  128.4067;
  290.8620  166.8350;
  373.0297  157.7144;
  332.8703  216.4153;
  273.0218  254.8435;
  202.9331  266.9322;
  282.1662  290.5292;
  222.3178  328.9575;
  152.2290  341.0462;
   82.9654  324.8867;
  146.7549  377.4758;
   76.6661  389.5645;
    7.4026  373.4051;
  -50.1006  331.5487;
  -11.8258  404.8273;
  -81.0894  388.6679;
 -138.5926  346.8115;
 -175.2569  285.8665]
```

Answer (score 0):

Really? All-caps?
Stackoverflow won't do your homework.

Here's something to get you started, though:
http://www.csi.ucd.ie/Staff/fcummins/NNcourse/intro.html

I used it to learn about neural networks and can attest it's an approachable read.

Technically, the correct answer would be "Simply implement a neural network and run the data through it". There's nothing special about this data and any neural network should be able to learn it.

Comment: While the question is not helpful your resource listed above is.